# How can I position content under a top bar and next to a side bar?

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to do: 
http://gyazo.com/9332c173b5d2ac761565f47636a5cfc0.png

I've tried positioning the sidebar using float:left but then it starts under the top bar...

I have no clue how to do this.

Help me, please!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamakeer/9rmQt/) that would work for you.

code:

```
<div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="topbar">topbar</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
```

and with css:

```
div{
border: 1px solid red;
}
#sidebar{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
#contentWrapper{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
```